# image wont fit the whole vh , text centering

Tags: html, css

I have this problem where the image wont fit the whole vh, the problem is located in the somewhere from .gameStarted (HTML),CSS

I tried removing the margin on `gameStarted` tried adding `vh` to images , `min-height: ...` to images etc nothing seems to work and there is always space at the top, and now on the right.

`````````````````````````````````````````````js
/*  HERE IS THE JAVASCRIPT IF YOU ALL NEED IT */
const items = [{
    name: "Ferrari Portofino 2021",
    value: 250000,
    imageSrc: "https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/K0DGSuoYmpv34Jli04xH2g5nGfk=/0x0:5385x3029/1000x1000/filters:focal(2693x1515:2694x1516)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/22780648/COUNTACH_LPI800_4__2_.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Lamborghini Gallardo",
    value: 126000,
    imageSrc: "https://di-uploads-pod30.dealerinspire.com/bmwofschererville/uploads/2021/10/1-BMW-Exterior-1000x1000-Oct2021.png"
  },
  // Add more items and their values here
];

let currentScore = 0;
let item1, item2, correctIndex;

const item1Element = document.getElementById("item1");
const item2Element = document.getElementById("item2");
const scoreTextElement = document.getElementById("score-text");
const questionTextElement = document.getElementById("question-text");
const moreButton = document.getElementById("more");
const lessButton = document.getElementById("less");
const valueIndex = document.getElementById("valueIndex");
const navPlay = document.getElementById("playy")
const playNav = document.getElementById("playnav")

function startNewRound() {
  const index1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
  let index2;
  do {
    index2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
  } while (index2 === index1);

  item1 = items[index1];
  item2 = items[index2];

  item1Element.src = item1.imageSrc;
  item2Element.src = item2.imageSrc;
  setTimeout(function() {
    item1Element.style.opacity = 1;
    item2Element.style.opacity = 1;
  }, 100);

  questionTextElement.innerHTML = `${item2.name} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;${item1.name}`;
  document.getElementById("item1").textContent = item1.name + " " + formatCurrency(item1.value);
  document.getElementById("item2").textContent = item2.name + " " + formatCurrency(item2.value);

  correctIndex = item1.value > item2.value ? 0 : 1;

  moreButton.addEventListener("click", handleMoreClick);
  lessButton.addEventListener("click", handleLessClick);

}

// WHEN CLICKED #playy OPEN CATEGORIES POPUP
navPlay.addEventListener("click", function() {
  popup.style.display = "block"
});
//````````````````````````````````````````````




function handleMoreClick() {
  handleItemClick(0, correctIndex);
  showValue(0, correctIndex, item1, item2);
  removeClickListeners();
}

function handleLessClick() {
  handleItemClick(1, correctIndex);
  showValue(1, correctIndex, item1, item2);
  removeClickListeners();
}

function removeClickListeners() {
  moreButton.removeEventListener("click", handleMoreClick);
  lessButton.removeEventListener("click", handleLessClick);
}

function startNewGame() {
  currentScore = 0;
  scoreTextElement.textContent = `Score: ${currentScore}`;
  startNewRound();
}

function endGame() {
  moreButton.disabled = true;
  lessButton.disabled = true;

  const playAgainButton = document.createElement("button");
  playAgainButton.textContent = "Play Again";
  playAgainButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    moreButton.disabled = false;
    lessButton.disabled = false;
    valueIndex.style.display = "none";
    playAgainButton.remove();
    startNewGame();
  });

  questionTextElement.textContent = "Game Over!";
  questionTextElement.appendChild(playAgainButton);
}

function handleItemClick(clickedIndex, correctIndex) {
  if (clickedIndex === correctIndex) {
    currentScore++;
    scoreTextElement.textContent = `Score: ${currentScore}`;
    alert("You Guessed Correct");
  } else {
    endGame();
    return;
  }

  setTimeout(startNewRound, 1000);
}

function showValue(clickedIndex, correctIndex, item1, item2) {
  if (clickedIndex === correctIndex) {
    valueIndex.innerHTML = `${formatCurrency(item1.value)}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ${formatCurrency(item2.value)}`;
    valueIndex.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    valueIndex.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function formatCurrency(value) {
  return `$${value.toLocaleString()}`;
}






document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const playButton = document.querySelector(".play");
  const popup = document.getElementById("popup");
  const closePopupButton = document.getElementById("close-popup");
  const categoryButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".category");
  const gameStarted = document.querySelector(".gameStarted");
  const mainPage = document.getElementById("main-page");
  const main = document.querySelector("main");
  const body = document.querySelector("body");

  playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    popup.style.display = "block";
  });

  closePopupButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    popup.style.display = "none";
  });

  playNav.addEventListener("click", function() {
    popup.style.display = "none";
    mainPage.style.display = "none";
    gameStarted.style.display = "block";
    main.style.display = "none";
    gameStarted.classList.add('active');
    body.classList.add('active');
    startNewRound();
  });
  categoryButtons.forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
      popup.style.display = "none";
      mainPage.style.display = "none";
      gameStarted.style.display = "block";
      main.style.display = "none";
      gameStarted.classList.add('active');
      body.classList.add('active');
      startNewRound();
    });
  });
});
const items = [{
    name: "Ferrari Portofino 2021",
    value: 250000,
    imageSrc: "https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/K0DGSuoYmpv34Jli04xH2g5nGfk=/0x0:5385x3029/1000x1000/filters:focal(2693x1515:2694x1516)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/22780648/COUNTACH_LPI800_4__2_.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Lamborghini Gallardo",
    value: 126000,
    imageSrc: "https://di-uploads-pod30.dealerinspire.com/bmwofschererville/uploads/2021/10/1-BMW-Exterior-1000x1000-Oct2021.png"
  },
  // Add more items and their values here
];

let currentScore = 0;
let item1, item2, correctIndex;

const item1Element = document.getElementById("item1");
const item2Element = document.getElementById("item2");
const scoreTextElement = document.getElementById("score-text");
const questionTextElement = document.getElementById("question-text");
const moreButton = document.getElementById("more");
const lessButton = document.getElementById("less");
const valueIndex = document.getElementById("valueIndex");
const navPlay = document.getElementById("playy")
const playNav = document.getElementById("playnav")

function startNewRound() {
  const index1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
  let index2;
  do {
    index2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
  } while (index2 === index1);

  item1 = items[index1];
  item2 = items[index2];

  item1Element.src = item1.imageSrc;
  item2Element.src = item2.imageSrc;
  setTimeout(function() {
    item1Element.style.opacity = 1;
    item2Element.style.opacity = 1;
  }, 100);

  questionTextElement.innerHTML = `${item2.name} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;${item1.name}`;
  document.getElementById("item1").textContent = item1.name + " " + formatCurrency(item1.value);
  document.getElementById("item2").textContent = item2.name + " " + formatCurrency(item2.value);

  correctIndex = item1.value > item2.value ? 0 : 1;

  moreButton.addEventListener("click", handleMoreClick);
  lessButton.addEventListener("click", handleLessClick);

}

// WHEN CLICKED #playy OPEN CATEGORIES POPUP
navPlay.addEventListener("click", function() {
  popup.style.display = "block"
});
//````````````````````````````````````````````




function handleMoreClick() {
  handleItemClick(0, correctIndex);
  showValue(0, correctIndex, item1, item2);
  removeClickListeners();
}

function handleLessClick() {
  handleItemClick(1, correctIndex);
  showValue(1, correctIndex, item1, item2);
  removeClickListeners();
}

function removeClickListeners() {
  moreButton.removeEventListener("click", handleMoreClick);
  lessButton.removeEventListener("click", handleLessClick);
}

function startNewGame() {
  currentScore = 0;
  scoreTextElement.textContent = `Score: ${currentScore}`;
  startNewRound();
}

function endGame() {
  moreButton.disabled = true;
  lessButton.disabled = true;

  const playAgainButton = document.createElement("button");
  playAgainButton.textContent = "Play Again";
  playAgainButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    moreButton.disabled = false;
    lessButton.disabled = false;
    valueIndex.style.display = "none";
    playAgainButton.remove();
    startNewGame();
  });

  questionTextElement.textContent = "Game Over!";
  questionTextElement.appendChild(playAgainButton);
}

function handleItemClick(clickedIndex, correctIndex) {
  if (clickedIndex === correctIndex) {
    currentScore++;
    scoreTextElement.textContent = `Score: ${currentScore}`;
    alert("You Guessed Correct");
  } else {
    endGame();
    return;
  }

  setTimeout(startNewRound, 1000);
}

function showValue(clickedIndex, correctIndex, item1, item2) {
  if (clickedIndex === correctIndex) {
    valueIndex.innerHTML = `${formatCurrency(item1.value)}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ${formatCurrency(item2.value)}`;
    valueIndex.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    valueIndex.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function formatCurrency(value) {
  return `$${value.toLocaleString()}`;
}






document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const playButton = document.querySelector(".play");
  const popup = document.getElementById("popup");
  const closePopupButton = document.getElementById("close-popup");
  const categoryButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".category");
  const gameStarted = document.querySelector(".gameStarted");
  const mainPage = document.getElementById("main-page");
  const main = document.querySelector("main");
  const body = document.querySelector("body");

  playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    popup.style.display = "block";
  });

  closePopupButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    popup.style.display = "none";
  });

  playNav.addEventListener("click", function() {
    popup.style.display = "none";
    mainPage.style.display = "none";
    gameStarted.style.display = "block";
    main.style.display = "none";
    gameStarted.classList.add('active');
    body.classList.add('active');
    startNewRound();
  });
  categoryButtons.forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
      popup.style.display = "none";
      mainPage.style.display = "none";
      gameStarted.style.display = "block";
      main.style.display = "none";
      gameStarted.classList.add('active');
      body.classList.add('active');
      startNewRound();
    });
  });
});
`````````````````````````````````````````````

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Ink Free;
}


/*SET THE NAVIGATION BAR AT THE TOP OF THE SCREEN, REMOVE BACKGROUND COLOR AND BOX SHADOW LATER ON*/

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
}


/*SETTING THE LOGO COLOR AND ANIMATION*/

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

h1>a:hover {
  margin-left: 2rem;
  transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}


/*SETTING THE NAVBAR*/

li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-left: 0.6rem;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}

li>a:hover {
  color: bisque;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: 0.25s ease-out;
}

h1>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}


/*BACKGROUND IMAGE SET TO FIT, CHANGE THE WIDTH AND HEIGHT VH IF NEEDED, OPACITY TO 1 OR REMOVE*/

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #240303 10%, #aa5625);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0.96;
}


/*THE MAIN TEXT AT THE MIDDLE OF THE SCREEN*/

.wwm {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.title {
  font-size: 5rem;
}


/*PLAY BUTTON NEEDS JAVASCRIPT*/

.play {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding: 0rem 3rem;
  background-color: rgba(122, 64, 72, 0);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  border: 0.125rem solid #fff;
}

.play:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 252, 252);
  transition: .50s ease-in-out;
  color: black;
}


/*chatgpt*/

.popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 1000;
  padding-top: 350px;
}

.popup-content {
  background: white;
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-align: center;
}

.categories {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.category {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.category:hover {
  background-color: wheat;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.50s ease;
}

.close-popup {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #DC3545;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  padding: 0rem 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.close-popup:hover {
  background-color: red;
  transition: 0.50s ease;
}

.gameStarted {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  /* Change the position to relative */
  margin-top: 0;
  /* Remove the top margin */
}

.gameStarted.active {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  /* Change the position to relative */
  margin-top: 0;
  /* Remove the top margin */
}

.divv {
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.body.active {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(30 41 59/var(--tw-bg-opacity));
  transition: 1s ease;
}


/* Style the game container */

.line {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 50vh;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.vs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 44px;
  /* Adjust font size as needed */
  font-weight: bold;
  /* Optionally make the text bold */
  z-index: 101;
}

.imgtxt {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  top: 69%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 160rem;
}

:root {
  --color: white;
  --font-size: 3rem;
}

.dog {
  background-color: var(--color);
  /* Use the variable --main-color */
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

@import url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/rooneysans');
.question-text {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%, 350%);
  width: 98vw;
  font-family: 'RooneySans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
}


/* Add this CSS to your existing styles.css file */

#item1 {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 800px;
  min-width: 950px;
}

#item2 {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 900px;
  min-width: 950px;
}

.the-images {
  display: flex;
}

#more,
#less {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 0.8rem 5.5rem;
  color: #fff989;
  border-radius: 2.5rem;
  border: 0.125rem solid #fff;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

#more:hover,
#less:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  color: black;
  transition: 0.50s ease;
}

#less {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 0.8rem 5.7rem;
}

.buttons {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 75%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.score-text {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

#valueIndex {
  color: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Center horizontally */
  align-items: center;
  /* Center vertically */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(28%, -50%);
  width: 98vw;
  font-family: 'RooneySans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Whats Worth More</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body class="body">
  <main>
    <div id="main-page">
      <header class="navbar">
        <h1><a href="#">WWM</a></h1>
        <nav class="nav">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a id="playnav" href="#gameStarted">Play</a>
              <a id="playy" href="#popup">Gamemodes</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>
    <section class="main">
      <div class="wwm">
        <h2 class="title">Whats Worth More</h2>
        <button class="play" id="playy">Play</button>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="popup" id="popup">
      <div class="popup-content">
        <h2>Select a Gamemode</h2>
        <div class="categories">
          <button class="category">Classic</button>
        </div>
        <button class="close-popup" id="close-popup">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>


  <div class="gameStarted">
    <div class="line">
      <p class="vs">VS</p>
    </div>
    <div id="score-container" class="score-container">
      <p id="score-text" class="score-text">Score: 0</p>
    </div>
    <h2 id="question-text" class="question-text">

      <span class="item">${item2.name} ${item2.value}</span>
      <span class="space">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="item">${item1.name} ${item1.value}</span>

    </h2>

    <h3 id="valueIndex">
      <span class="value">${item2.value}</span>
      <span class="space">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="value">${item1.value}</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button id="more">
                More
               </button>
      <button id="less">
                Less
               </button>
    </div>

    <div class="the-images">
      <img id="item1" class="item" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/ADCreHcCjus21gcwf_7ZWtWnI1C8VF6il_oIJ5L0yCIuR-I5YOr_ZGzZLL14BeTxWL4TfNr1nwJqkdsQiIUjeTOrj9RNKSN-05eq91gQP4fWrPSKlqOeXcXdkZtKd1F0UlLruAfupEnybDoKx7BnduYLYM32LEZPy_qJqJoABqE4lhytYWFyo-uMbZ8GlV3IjTl4fWwRNT1hKMiQoX2J0marXDA5CrtrRq9nJQE0nH2rtSCSwZmJnCQc0PrEmeA_Rg5Ss6gDzvpwWr7dQmH0IfUCXxZiJl1HFNYGCoSr2Rm79hKdVJPlLWeaevPgwDJ7Yy9igO6IdMc77QNax3jA93bMYqkChm2wa40ev8HPs7h2Q_nteXUFq_b1r2I7ap866gONYBdE0qeZcd0uSudyzTgIyz9VTsiDKxIItR7aljYE_BfL2QZHKYWmqSvuxLx0FM85qczVPcH1BI-T3goi5EvvUOcKeTUJt3sUdZsr_LQoMPlYEa2bvQcTGlypCMI7hcTYOLwNPsKV1RFCJu4MxlcnLEO6S8S9dB6CkSPZQhijU_gxXehMkj64EdCVcOlzIda1r5HegE7KaHEEoxAv8XbhM0qpnjeQrMs1an8jNqAR6IL3LW-tcQlsGljFCf_XNp0adrHsLSlvablMdiRokWnYlU3dton4yw5-3KXPdr8G-EVSrTLf1C8HAZvRx0eoSTHEJD-hxjRbieVyzhHeSjBJ6mZGIHbfnwuhudLyxYlEPZkqWRAUin-oh_iQcNXSs_wLko-XCoDt0gllXM27oa5tdvfJk4PiUKBO-fa25MCxF0G4P8aKOh_WKPkIddRswVhUh3aTPNI6O9JbDJpgeA6n-pGx8vf1lS_e79wxFjcFJAoPtvxl423aB4Oe-xCZbZlVrVMJZPQAkOhFtOQOcNSZ1yq5XH9H6bz2G9q-g_I2BkCb1KwKJ5cftOR7vg=w707-h353-s-no?authuser=0"
        alt="Item 1">
      <img id="item2" class="item" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/ADCreHdP1_Kf_n02AGb882NS26oo4NnFmqUylj7ww8ecIoHje6Zl4z_uQ8_z8KpfF126leO4l_TImfWiy0dTE0CYApw_dekxeH6XedeRv3iMrrBfCm0Ds2BhakRUXStwNm8_YyNN4fcl3NnlLpN1jMls1ixO0-WG0hmshnuFgygug-qvuMyd8hpQW1HKwslTr-zPBn2M6t_odmoQUQAWQseNysVvrCo7me-9lnfmumG17oFie0S6Pj7mEE_q4BwiYk4fQ8iYxfiuDyGdbLlR6VmRdvkf7BlbZqA417AAdzyWohLSZoU2aY_K0EP0b-7oZF76AQYc6kQE-nd2QU9nhBT9Ij6SLNLdavFUQck4uqZzVSgUXPo81hGPpeywq_FF3ll37TlEMWnQSgSEm80xgmGP7KkWK-OIVpF_-CHrCqB-18d5LnRcut48HXjqPeJRXzxRntB0HVCFvq0nZWbI2OiMF3ILJWp09gyQWr3zLsM5CfDm3NWmVLy4LUg3BNNfJ9BdBNH0TdyFzEH6vxlQkaEtVY86K9eMJVc9tqt1T6LeBXxh55YtK0XVO7Kq7Wk0JUAh6J_OqqSMtZNBYEDPOge0FXLuGLXXlZ-hDxYQjlOA4-J6ALAEY6qlcKdQu_iG6sDToC0nBlbAUmq0JYk194q8ojYxfHps-HoYCZxFeauawiC2mY49omlR_YEslegwi79DMOttecI56CdqWK6Syd_mOsd57lM9eJJ4_r2U3BUC1YHfL8bEVIAqqYQJCwkMP1wa8UYbc3gjDpmQBNNZ_dMvT2rnlYBH-S46BCeYnJH_WHPzK0NXLY5p7Qtk41o2EFoyX0843UySheVz_oRAWzQdY0-nt4DNIPOeNo7WSBqtRF9e00UevzidggdRcgZgLU4xacjkkpy6k7YhY9xsFlwUfuXvm6uuBVSAtJN3m9Gg630Jn6QgX1lb7LOn7A=w654-h381-s-no?authuser=0"
        alt="Item 2">
    </div>





  </div>

  <script src="questions.js"></script>
  <script src="game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```